# Implementing jquery DataTable in XPages

Tags: xpages

I am attempting to implement my first jquery DataTable in XPages and cannot get even a basic HTML version to initialise.

I have added the downloaded files to my WebContent folder in Package Explorer. So I have ....

WebContent - DataTables- examples/extensions/media etc. in the folders.

I have modified my application theme which works fine with everything else to include......

```
<resource>
<content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
<href>DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js</href>
</resource>
<resource>
<content-type>text/css</content-type>
<href>DataTables/extensions/FixedColumns/css/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.css</href>
</resource>
<resource>
<content-type>text/css</content-type>
<href>DataTables/extensions/FixedColumns/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js</href>
</resource>
<resource> <content-type>text/css</content-type>
<href>DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css</href>
</resource>
```

I have added a script block on my page

```
`<xp:scriptBlock>
 <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
$("#tableSimple").DataTable(); 
 } 
 ); 
]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

And I have used the sample data from the DataTable web site.

```
<table id="tableSimple" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>.....etc
```

No matter what I cannot get the DataTable to load. I have tried Oliver Busse's nsf from his blog on the same subject and cannot get it to work either.

I am clearly missing something and I am somewhat of a novice,  so sorry if it is a basic question, but I am losing the will to live on this! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's most likely an AMD loader issue. Search SO for that

Comment: Hi Per Henrik, are you able to confirm what I have above is correct so far?

Comment: You need to fix the AMD loading issue in order for datatables to work with XPages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this working. Frustratingly I cannot determine where the fault was. I could only solve it by deleting all previously copied elements and copying every relevant element from the Michael Smith example into my application.

I did note that tables cannot be `<xp:table>` which I didn't realise for a while.

Many thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing the AMD issue.  Google AMD and XPages and you will see possible solutions  - like https://xomino.com/2015/06/08/fixing-the-xpages-r9-dojo-define-amd-problem-once-and-for-all/

Howard

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, are you extending "webstandard" or a bootstrap version?  You have to have jQuery listed in the html head before the dataTables.js.  What do you have listed on your page?

I've had this working in many apps, and here is the html head for one XPage I have that includes a jQuery dataTable (I've omitted irrelevant lines):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In the theme, I have it set to "webstandard" to make sure that jQuery is first and I have all the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I think the AMD issue is already fixed in Oliver's DB? (I may be wrong?)

If you enable firebug/developer tools, do any errors show up on the console tab? Or are any errors showing up in the domino log?

Also, do the table headers get drawn and just not the content, or are you not even getting a table header?

The only other thing that jumps out slightly, is Oliver used bower for the installation, where as you have copy/pasted the resources you need. As such, the file structure is slightly different, so may be worth checking if there are any references to files/scripts with the bower file path?

Oh, and are you using resource aggregation? I think some of the CSS uses relative paths so you might just need to update these?

Are you initialising the table?

Comment: Thanks Chris and the others. I have tried virtually everything here. To answer your specific questions, I have added the AMD snippet etc, yes I get the table. I have now gone to the extent of copying in the resources from Michael Smith's demo which works fine on my server, but still no. I do receive errors trying to fine the CSS files but the path is correct! The most likely error though is the $(...).DataTable is not a function error. Which I guess is where the problem lies.

Comment: Sorted the CSS errors, which just leaves me with the .DataTable function error, clearly the suspect. I could do with knowing where this function should be or why it is broken.

Comment: This final issue sounds like what Steve Cochrane mentioned --- You need to load DataTables AFTER jQuery scripts. Also, make sure you only include jQuery once. There's a chance you may have included it twice if you copied from another nsf maybe?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did have DataTables after jQuery, but clearly I had something wrong, - see my answer, - all the links in the browser page source resolved fine everything seemed in order, but clearly it was not. so I'm not sure where it was wrong.